# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition' (windows COMPUTER)

Tags: python, windows, speech-recognition, pyaudio

My installation command was:

```
pip install speechrecognition
pip install pyAudio
```

In my file it raise this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/Projects/Python/Assistant/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import speech_recognition as sr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'
```

And my code was:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
```

Comment: According to [here](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) the command is `pip install SpeechRecognition`

Comment: I did that. `pip install SpeechRecognition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said earlier, the correct command is `pip install SpeechRecognition` and then import like so... `import speech_recognition as sr` then when ready to use it, implement it like this...

```
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:

        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = .5
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
        print("User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Unable to understand.")
        return "None"

    return query
```

You want to make sure that exception handler is in there. This is done from documentation.

***EDIT***

The issue may also be the version of Python. SpeechRecognition isn't supported for Python 3.7 and above. I tested it for Python 3.6 and it worked perfectly. They do need to release a working version for the newer Python versions.

Comment: I installed speech_recognition like that. But I still got that error.

Comment: What version of python are you using

Comment: 3.8.5 is the version of python that i'm using

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Using Visual Studio Code. Found out that my python interpreter was looking at the wrong virtual environment. I changed the location using `control + shift + P` to the location of my current files that I installed speech recognition. I am using version 3.9 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my bug!
I don't know what the error was but it's fixed!

Comment: The problem was that I was not using the python that speachrecoginition was stored.